# OAuthException Facebook and OSQA

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, osqa

I'm using OSQA and I simply trying to login with Facebook (without any change on the platform code), only setting 'app secret' and 'app id'.

My Facebook App settings:

```
Site URL: http://localhost:8080/osqa/
Canvas URL: http://localhost:8080/osqa/osqa/account/facebook/done/
```

I encounter this error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191
   }
}
```

and this is the url with the redirect_uri

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?scope=email&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8080%2Fosqa%2Fosqa%2Faccount%2Ffacebook%2Fdone%2F&client_id=***
```

I read a lot of posts concerning this problem here on stackoverflow and in other forums, I know there is a simple solution, but cannot figure out yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redirect in your URL translates to this:

```
redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/osqa/osqa/account/facebook/done/
```

Facebook just checks the strings and sees that `127.0.0.1` is not the same as `localhost`. So replace this in your app settings and the redirect should work.

Comment: It gives me back a 404 with this URL

"http://127.0.0.1:8080/osqa/osqa/account/facebook/done/?code=***"

I delete one occurence of osqa/ and works well. Now I must figure out how to solve the new problem

Comment: Check your `APP_URL` setting in `settings_local.py`. Pay attention to the comment above: `# This shouldn't be followed by a trailing slash.`

Comment: APP_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/osqa'

If I delete "/osqa" I obtain an unuseless URL  "http://127.0.0.1:8080/account/facebook/done/?code=***"

Maybe is a bug somewhere else?

Comment: On urls.py I have:

"url(r'^%s(?P<provider>\w+)/%s$' % (_('account/'), _('done/')), app.auth.process_provider_signin, name='auth_provider_done'),"

Comment: So if you delete `/osqa` one time from the `APP_URL` setting, it is removed twice from the `redirect_uri`? Try changing `_('done/')` to `_('done')`.

Comment: Yes. I've tried: "127.0.0.1:8080/osqa/osqa/account/facebook/done?code=***" instead of "127.0.0.1:8080/osqa/osqa/account/facebook/done/?code=***"

Comment: In the method `process_provider_signin(request, provider)` from `url(r'^%s(?P<provider>\w+)/%s$' % (_('account/'), _('done/')), app.auth.process_provider_signin, name='auth_provider_done'),` inside it there is `assoc_key = provider_class.process_authentication_request(request)`. The method `process_authentication_request(self, request):` has this line `args = dict(client_id=settings.FB_API_KEY, redirect_uri="%s%s" % (django_settings.APP_URL, request.path))` Maybe this last line is the problem.

Comment: Yeah, this is probably a bug there. You could try fix it, or as a dirty workaround hardcode your `redirect_uri` there ;) As you're `APP_URL` contains only one `/osqa` there is probably a `/osqa` to much in `request.path`.

Comment: Here is the solution for the second problem ;) http://meta.osqa.net/questions/11746/facebook-login-bug-in-subfolder-install-subfolder-part-of-url-appears-twice-during-login-redirect